# Clustering based on distance in offline mode

Tags: android, location, cluster-analysis, k-means

On my android app I have location points (latitude and longitude) with some info connected to them (but itsn't important here).

I want to get centroids coordinate for that dataset with a conditions that distance between centroid and all points in cluster are less than 500m (1000m diameter).

The size of each cluster is irrevelant but i do not know how to estimate number of clusters and what library use for that task.

I found several answears here but mostly based on R, python or GoogleAPI but my app assume no internet connection that's why i use shortest distance not based on any maps.

Answer (score 0):

Just roll your own. It's easy.

Typical marker clusters do not optimize anything. They just as markers except if a distance threshold is violated. To close markers are merged into one.

Finding the optimum solution would likely be nice, so you have to settle for something like this anyway.